# How to add an Action to Account Controller in Shopware

Tags: events, shopware

How to add a custom action to an existing Controller in Shopware?

Examples (url structure):

```
/account/bonus
/account/custom
/account/...
```

Usually it's easier and cleaner to create a new controller for that purpose, but in some cases it's necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Spoiler:** Replace the controller

There is no cleaner way than to replace the whole controller and extend it's functionality, so it's nearly as *clean* as Shopware's hooks.

**Guide**

Add a new Subscriber to your Plugin

```
class AccountSubscriber implements SubscriberInterface
{
    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            'Enlight_Controller_Dispatcher_ControllerPath_Frontend_Account' => 'getAccountController'
        );
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAccountController()
    {
        return $this->getPath() . '/Controllers/Frontend/AccountExtended.php';
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPath()
    {
        $plugin = Shopware()->Container()->get('kernel')->getPlugins()['AcmeYourPlugin'];

        return $plugin->getPath();

    }
}
```

**Downsides**

Unfortunately some controller have private methods which impact the logic. Like the Account Controller. So it's not always possible to simply extend the controller.

In the end, try to add a new controller with a new route.
It's easier, and cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

You should not replace the "account" controller.
You can define you own action for existing controller with following:

```
public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            'Enlight_Controller_Action_Frontend_Account_MyBonus'        => 'onAccountMyBonus',        
      ];
    }
```

and then

```
public function onAccountMyBonus(\Enlight_Event_EventArgs $args)
    {
        $args->setProcessed(true);
        .....
         your code here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a cleaner way than replacing the whole Controller.
It is also not recommended to replace a whole controller due to the lack of update compatibility.
In the worst case something like that could kill the whole website.
A while ago I created a thread in the [shopware forum](https://forum.shopware.com/discussion/48179/finishaction-uebersichtlich-erweitern#latest) *(german)* discussing the exact same issue. I wanted to **extend** an existing finishAction() in the checkout Controller.

```
public function onPostDispatchCheckout(\Enlight_Controller_ActionEventArgs $args)
{
/** @var \Enlight_Controller_Action $controller */
$controller = $args->getSubject();

/** @var \Enlight_Controller_Request_Request $request */
$request = $controller->Request();

if ($request->getActionName() !== 'finish') {
    return;
}

// do your stuff here
}
```

So even though it is not the exact same issue you have, the procedure is quite the same.

First off you subscribe to the controller (in my case the PostDispatchCheckout Controller) afterwards you edit the controller in your Bootstrap.php

To make sure, that it just alters a specific action you **have** to use the if-construction so your code gets just triggered on the wished action [in my case the finishAction()].

I hope this helps. What wonders me though is why you have to add a **new** action to an already existing controller. I can think of no situation where something like that is more practicable than creating a complete new custom controller.

Kind regards,

Max

Comment: In my concrete use case I had to implement a second registration page on a different route. With the same login functionality from the Account controller.

**The problem**:
Shopware's Account controller forwards all requests to a Register controller internally in some cases (eg. wrong login credentials).

I'm aware of the post/pre dispatch way to extend controllers functionality, but in my case it wasn't possible.