# How to extend Shopware 6 controller action

Tags: php, plugins, controller, shopware, shopware6

I am building a plugin for Shopware 6 and cannot seem to find any documentation as to how to extend an existing controller action. I found this [How to add an Action to Account Controller in Shopware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46340089/how-to-add-an-action-to-account-controller-in-shopware) but it seems to refer to Shopware 5 and I am not sure I can use it that way in Shopware 6.

The controller action I want to extend is `\Shopware\Storefront\Controller\AddressController::saveAddress` - in my case I want to add custom address validation that would use a service in my plugin where a request to 3rd party API would be made, if the address is correct then allow the address, if not then return an error. Perhaps it is better to instead extend `\Shopware\Core\Checkout\Customer\SalesChannel\AddressService::save` but I have no clue for now (I am new to Shopware in general). Extending the service would mean I do not have to override the whole action logic so that it contains my check in the middle. Or perhaps there is an event I can use for address saving (same thing, can't find a good source/list of events for Shopware6).

There seem to be guides here:
https://docs.shopware.com/en/shopware-platform-dev-en/developer-guide/controller
and here:
https://docs.shopware.com/en/shopware-platform-dev-en/how-to/custom-storefront-controller
but these only describe how to make a new controller and it is not very useful to me since I do not want to add any new routes but use the existing one `/account/address/create`.

I would be very grateful for a code example of how to register the override in the plugin (config, xml) and how would the extending class look like. If it is not too much to ask the ideal answer would contain an example of:

1. How to extend an action for existing controller.
2. How to extend an existing service.
3. Where to find which event is firing in a controller/service, subscribe to it and make it override default behaviour (like throw `Shopware\Core\Framework\Validation\Exception\ConstraintViolationException`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. It does not make sense to extend/override action, as action should be as thin as it is possible, and all business logic should be in service.
2. To extend existing service you can decorate it or subscribe to some events to extend functionality. See https://docs.shopware.com/en/shopware-platform-dev-en/how-to/decorating-a-service
3. In your case, you can subscribe on `framework.validation.address.create` or/and `framework.validation.address.update` events to extend list of constraints. In general all validation events have prefix `framework.validation.` second part is defined in `\Shopware\Core\Framework\Validation\DataValidationFactoryInterface` implementation in your case it is `\Shopware\Core\Checkout\Customer\Validation\AddressValidationFactory`

Comment: Number 3. looks promising. I have subscribed to `Shopware\Core\Checkout\Customer\CustomerEvents::MAPPING_ADDRESS_CREATE` and it allows me to use `Shopware\Core\Framework\Event\DataMappingEvent` to get access to entered address data - do you know how to make it write back validation result (if it did not validate then supress address creation and return an error message back to `Shopware\Core\Checkout\Customer\SalesChannel::upsert`) ?

Comment: You need to subscribe to framework.validation.address.create event. There you can extend $event->getDefinition() object. you can add here your own validation rules.
Then everything will work automatically. Check `\Shopware\Core\Checkout\Customer\Validation\AddressValidationFactory::buildCommonValidation` for better understanding.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, seems to be working now.

For others: I have created a new validator and added it to `Shopware\Core\Framework\Validation\DataValidationDefinition` via `add` method in my subscriber. Then I created a validator in the same directory (same class name but with Validator at the end - is being found and used automatically). That validation checks if the street number is TRUE - meaning it always fails but I only attach it if 3rd party address validation fails. A little hacky but it works.