# How to subscribe to predispatch of registration in Shopware 6 just like shopware 5?

Tags: shopware

I want to call a function right before the registration process starts in order to check some values from the registration form. In Shopware 5 I would use a predispatch event for that. How to do that in Shopware 6?

This is the method into which the form posts the registration data to:

```
/**
 * @Route("/account/register", name="frontend.account.register.save", methods={"POST"})
 * @Captcha
 */
public function register(Request $request, RequestDataBag $data, SalesChannelContext $context): Response
{
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the class Shopware\Core\Checkout\Customer\CustomerEvents.
MAPPING_REGISTER_CUSTOMER should be the one you are looking for.

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Plugin\Subscriber;

use Shopware\Core\Checkout\Customer\CustomerEvents;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\Event\DataMappingEvent;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;

class RegisterSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            CustomerEvents::MAPPING_REGISTER_CUSTOMER => 'onRegister'
        ];
    }

    public function onRegister(DataMappingEvent $event)
    {
        $input = $event->getInput();
        $output = $event->getOutput();

        // do whatever you want here with the output

        $event->setOutput($output);

        return true;
    }
}
```

The subscriber is registered in services.xml like this, similar to Shopware 5, except the ID is the FQDN of the subscriber class:

```
    <!-- Event Subscribers -->
    <service id="Vendor\Plugin\Subscriber\RegisterSubscriber">
        <tag name="kernel.event_subscriber"/>
    </service>
```

Comment: I was thinking that the event was the CustomerEvents::CUSTOMER_REGISTER_EVENT

Comment: Is the MAPPING_REGISTER_CUSTOMER called before the registration process starts? Is it like the predispatch of sw5 or postdispatchsecure?

Answer (score 1):

I think the earliest event on which you can subscribe it is `framework.validation.customer.create`.
It is dispatched at `RegisterRoute::getCustomerCreateValidationDefinition()`. In subscriber you can extend validation constraints.
if you need to do something earlier i think the best solution is to override/decorate `RegisterRoute`.

You can check my answer there [How to extend Shopware 6 controller action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63261991/how-to-extend-shopware-6-controller-action/63262759#63262759), it may help also.

Comment: 'framework.validation.customer.address.number.validation.update' => 'onRegister'
is that the event name that can be subscribed with a function?

And how are the validation constraints extended?
Is there any reference or documentation on it?

Comment: I am sorry copied the wrong event, just edited it. the correct one is `framework.validation.customer.create`

Comment: After that you can define subscriber method like this:
`onRegister(BuildValidationEvent $event) {
   $definition = $event->getDefinition();
   $definition->add('someField', new NotBlank());
}
`